# How to tell default c++ version (without explicit flag) for my compiler?

Tags: c++, gcc

I am using `gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)`

Where to look for it? I know how to add flags to force a particular standard with GNU extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [Jesper Juhl said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38083043/25507), checking the docs is probably best.

If you want, though, you can also ask your compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char**) {
  cout << __cplusplus << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

From the GCC docs on [predefined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros), this will output one of the following:

> 199711L for the 1998 C++ standard, 201103L for the 2011 C++ standard, 201402L for the 2014 C++ standard, or an unspecified value strictly larger than 201402L for the experimental languages enabled by -std=c++1z and -std=gnu++1z.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading the documentation? `man g++` is one place to start...  But, to answer the question; that gcc version compiles as C++98 by default (actually, the GNU variant).

If you want to detect the C++version in use without reading documentation or without specifying `-std=`, then you could just try compiling some code using only C++98,  some using C++03 features, C++11 features and C++14 features and see which one(s) it accept.
But just reading the docs is easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the predefined macro `__cplusplus`:

```
$ echo __cplusplus | g++ -E -x c++ -c -
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"
199711L
```

Explanation of command line arguments:

- `-E` - only run preprocessor
- `-x c++` - input file is a C++ source file (necessary for `__cplusplus` to be defined)
- `-c -` - read from stdin

Alternatively, the `-dM` option will dump all predefined macros:

```
$ g++ -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null | grep __cplusplus
#define __cplusplus 199711L
```